# Wrapped packaging model?

Tags: modeling, uv

I want to make a plastic wrapped packaging as shown in the photo. its wrapped and folds on sides towards the back and overleaps.

[image: wrapped box]

where should i start? I tried playing around with vertices in edit mode after adding a simple box, but i am having problems with getting the realistic fold effect. thanks

Comment: dynatopo starting with a scaled cube.

Comment: So the problem is not related to the modeling Process? if so You can use the cloth on collision object with high subdivide mesh and in the cloth properties play with the structura and bending i used 100 and 3 and it seems what you're looking for